# Printing table contents using Html::TreeBuilder::XPath

Tags: html, perl, html-table, html-tree

I want to extract all the tables from an html file and print their contents in the following way each cell seperated by `\t`, each row separated by `\n` and each table separated by  `\n\n`. The following is my script, when I changed it to findvalues on tr then whole tr is inserted as one element, and I even tried the other methods such as findnodes_as_strings ($path), I want to modify it to the above mentioned structure  .

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree= HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->parse_file( "html.html");

my @values=$tree->findvalues(q{//table//tr//td});

print $_, "\n" foreach(@values);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [HTML::TableExtract](http://blog.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to process each table separately, same for rows:

```
foreach my $table ( $tree->findnodes('//table') ) {

    foreach my $row ( $table->findnodes('.//tr') ) {

        my @cells = $row->findvalues('.//td');
        print join("\t", @cells), "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Of course this is solution only for **simple tables** (think about columnspans, th, table inside table etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot , its exactly what i expected .